# How to customize Internet Explorer button on mouse

Tags: mouse

Recently, I lost my USB plug for my mouse, so I had to use my backup mouse, and it has a button in the middle of it, below the scroll wheel, that has the internet explorer logo on it. Back when I used this mouse on my Windows computer, the button ended up setting itself to typing this whenever it was pushed: "www.bit.ly/upcpromo2018[return]", and now using it on my Mac, it does the same thing. I would like to change that, but I can't figure out how. It's a wireless mouse, it doesn't have any side buttons, on the top it says Universal Orlando Studios Partner Comm (smudge), and on the bottom is a label saying

```
2.4GHz Wireless Optical Mouse
Model NO.: TUV2406
Rating : 1.5V === 6.8mA
Tested To Comply With FCC Standards
FOR HOME OR OFFICE USE
```

Here are some pictures:

[image: Top/Side view of mouse]

[image: Bottom view of mouse]

Comment: What have you done to try and figure this out for yourself? Have you goggled for a manual or software to configure it?

Comment: Yeah, I looked everywhere, and there doesn't seem to be any manuals for this mouse, and I couldn't find software I could get working on my computer

Comment: Looking at [https://fccid.io/TUV2406](https://fccid.io/TUV2406) and [https://fccid.io/TUV2406/User-Manual/Users-Manual-1533741.pdf](https://fccid.io/TUV2406/User-Manual/Users-Manual-1533741.pdf) I'd say it's time to get a new mouse.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to customize IE button on mouse

In short, you probably can't. Let me explain.

A quick Google search for "TUV2406" does supply with a user manual, but it is very limited. It does provide you with the specifications for the mouse and it does mention under the **Compatible** section "no need driver" [sic].

There are two more clues to this mystery.

1. The "www.bit.ly/upcpromo2018" address leads to a Universal Parks & Resorts Partner Community.
2. The Universal Orlando Partner Community logo you mentioned.

This leads me to believe that it was a special promo item. Since there is no software for this mouse the web address that the IE button directs to is probably hard-coded into the mouse firmware.

It would be easier to get another mouse than to try and reprogram the button.

Comment: That seems logical, however originally the button did not do that. On my windows computer, it would just open the RUN box (What opens with win+r), and then it eventually started opening the run box and typing in that address, and when I used it on my Mac, it would just type in the address.

Comment: With no software to be installed, that seems like odd behavior.